# Catch SOAP Exception .NET

Tags: .net, exception, soap

I'd like how to catch a soap exception properly. I'm only able to catch it as a system.net.webexception (Error 500 HTTP) but not as a soapheaderexception or a soap exception.

My current code is:

```
Try
       'Code

Catch soapExcpHeader As System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException
            'Can't catch here
            Dim error_desc As String = soapExcpHeader.Detail.OuterXml
            Throw New System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException()
Catch soapExcp As System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
            'Can't catch here
            Dim error_desc As String = soapExcp.Detail.OuterXml
            Throw New System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
Catch webExcp As System.Net.WebException
             'Here I catch
            Console.WriteLine(webExcp.ToString())
            Throw webExcp
Catch ex as Exception
             'Other types of exceptions
             Throw ex
End Try
```

As always thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what is the value of the GetType() property of your exception, if your catch block doesn't stop on System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException, it means that your exception doesn't inherit of it.